# Enable Case Sensitive when using DataTable.select

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, case-sensitive

My database includes only

> Truck

however my below select statment returns the rows with 'Truck'

```
MyWebControl.Myfunction().Select("TransportationMode = '" + TRUCK + "'");
```

How can I make this select statement case sensitive ?

Comment: What is `TRUCK`? A string initialized to "TRUCK"?

Comment: Both 'Truck' and 'TRUCK' are strings here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set [`DataTable.CaseSensitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.casesensitive.aspx) to `True`.

Assuming `Myfunction()` returns a DataTable:

```
string TRUCK = "trUck";
var dt = MyWebControl.Myfunction();
dt.CaseSensitive = True;
dt.Select("TransportationMode = '" + TRUCK + "'");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're at least on .NET 3.5 you could use `linq` which is much more powerful and readable than the `DataTable.Select` syntax.

```
string mode = "Truck";
var rows = table.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(r = > r.Field<string>("TransportationMode") == mode);
```

It's case sensitive by default.